# Mnemonic button fires Click event of a button but it's not firing Leave event of TextBox

Tags: windows, forms, events

I have a Windows Forms with a few TextBoxes and a button. The button has a mnemonic key to get fired (example &OK). I'm subscribed to the Leave event of the TextBox in order to make a validation and update the related controls based on the user input (for example, if I change the cost of a product, the rentability proportion is going to be updated). If I click the OK button, everything works OK but if I use the mnemonic key (Alt+O), the Leave event of the TextBox is fired after the Click event of the button. Because of this, my TextBoxes are not updated before the Click event of the button. Any ideas?

Summary of normal behavior:
- Update TextBox value and click on OK button --> TextBox fires Leave Event and values are updated. Then, The Click event of the is handled.

Summary of strange behavior:
- Update TextBox value and press the shotcut key (Alt+O) for the OK button --> Click Event of the button is fired and then the Leave event of the TextBox is fired.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution using pieces of code from different places. I think that it's important to write it down here because I haven't found the complete answer anywhere. Even a question related to this issue is difficult to find. Let me explain what I did:

1) Override the method ProcessMnemonic in the Form.

```
        protected override bool ProcessMnemonic(char charCode)
        {
            // get the mnemonic key of the button that submits the form (accepts the form or performs some action)
            char mnemonicChar = DesignerHelper.GetMnemonicChar(btnCreate);
            // check if the button has a mnemonic key and if the mnemonic key pressed corresponds to it
            if (mnemonicChar != ' ' && charCode == mnemonicChar)
            {
            // get the control that is focused. this could be the textbox where the mnemonic key was pressed
                Control ctrl = DesignerHelper.FindFocusedControl(this);
                if (ctrl != null)
                {
                // fire the necessary event to update the state of the controls. in my case it's leave event.
                    DesignerHelper.FireEvent(ctrl, "Leave", new EventArgs());
                }
            }
            return base.ProcessMnemonic(charCode);
        }
```

2) Methods available in my own DesignerHelper class:

```
        public static Control FindFocusedControl(Control control)
        {
            var container = control as ContainerControl;
            while (container != null)
            {
                control = container.ActiveControl;
                container = control as ContainerControl;
            }
            return control;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Programatically fire an event handler of an object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetObject"></param>
        /// <param name="eventName"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public static void FireEvent(Object targetObject, string eventName, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             * By convention event handlers are internally called by a protected
             * method called OnEventName
             * e.g.
             *     public event TextChanged
             * is triggered by
             *     protected void OnTextChanged
             * 
             * If the object didn't create an OnXxxx protected method,
             * then you're screwed. But your alternative was over override
             * the method and call it - so you'd be screwed the other way too.
             */

            //Event thrower method name //e.g. OnTextChanged
            String methodName = "On" + eventName;

            MethodInfo mi = targetObject.GetType().GetMethod(
                  methodName,
                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            if (mi == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Cannot find event thrower named " + methodName);

            mi.Invoke(targetObject, new object[] { e });
        }

        internal static char GetMnemonicChar(Button btn)
        {
            if (btn.UseMnemonic && btn.Text.Contains("&"))
            {
                return btn.Text.Substring(btn.Text.IndexOf("&") + 1, 1)[0];
            }

            return ' ';
        }
```

Comment: The `GetMnemonicChar` method doesn't seem to solve every scenario. The `&&` substring is possible, which represents an escaped `&`, but not a mnemonic. Still, your method would return this ampersand, which is wrong. Your method should only return an ampersand if the `&&&` substring is found. Perhaps something like `new Regex("(?<!&)&([^&])").Match(btn.Text).Groups[1].Value[0]` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try with some trick ..

```
Dim sButtonBy as String

Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus      
    sButtonBy = ""
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.Alt Then sButtonBy = "KB"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    UpdateIt()
End Sub

Sub UpdateIt()

    'codes here

End Sub
```

EDITED :

```
Use this sub to handle every button that added dynamically

AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Me.Buttons_Click

Private Sub Buttons_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If sButtonBy = "KB" Then updateit()

    'codes here

End Sub
```

Comment: This is going to work as works the workaround I proposed but it's not very nice to have a field with key pressed and check for it in the click event handler. What would happen if I have 10 buttons? and every time I add a button with a mnemonic shortcut I have to update the source code too. It's to error prone.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein .. dont worry about that, you just need to make a sub that handled all your buttons's click event .. it's updated ..

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it but I don't think that it's the best solution. There has to be a better solution but unfortunately I haven't found it yet :)

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein .. I think this could help you .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processmnemonic.aspx

Comment: With your solution, you don't know which event has not been fired. You could have many TextBoxes subscribed to the Leave event and you should check which one has to be fired in your updateit() method. That's why I think it's better to focus the button in the Click event handler as I commented below. Focusing on the button forces the Leave event of the focused control.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "LostFocus" Event Instead of using "Leave"...

Comment: That is a Really Bad idea.  Read the MSDN article for the problems with that event.  Nor does it solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is the same, the TextBox events are not getting fired because of the way that mnemonic keys work.